# Two maven dependencies depend include one common dependency in different versions

Tags: maven, dependencies, dependency-management

I have two dependencies, A and B, which depend on a third common package, C. But they depend on different versions of C, meaning, some method names in C differ between A and B.

If I now include both A and B as dependencies in my project in this order, A will include its C, and B will use the classes of A as well, because they are first in the classpath.

Since the version of C, that B was compiled for, is different from the version A includes, B cannot find the correct methods to call.

How to solve this?

I cannot exclude either C from A nor C from B. I cannot rebuild A or B. Can I do some classloader magic, so that A and B don't see each other?

Comment: I cannot change A or B, but I can build C. I am thinking about building a C variant, with methods from both versions, and include that one first. But that would be a lot of work and maintanance, if the upstream changes. I'd rather have a different solution.

Answer (score 1):

The best way will be ask maintainer of `A` and `B` to use the latest version of `C`. Of course it can be difficult in sometime.

You can also try to contribute to projects `A` or/and `B` and propose change - don't afraid such steps.

As workaround, you can create own package AA with dependencies to A and C will also be on path as transitive dependency.

Then in `AA` you can use [maven-shade-plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/class-relocation.html) to build uber JAR and relocating classes only used in `C`.

Now you can use in your project `AA` which will contains all classes from `A` in the the same packages and hidden classes from `C`.